# How to redirect URL in Azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I was wondering what is the approach to have URL rewrite or redirection for example:

if a user hit blabla.mydomain.com I want to be routed to blabla.mydomain.com/myapp

how it can be done using Azure application gateway? the backend is IIS with .net 3.1

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your HTTPSettings of your Application Gateway, there is an option called "Override backend path" where you can add a path **/myapp** to override the path / to /myapp .

[image]

You can have more clarity on Override backend path from this GitHub issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51222